# Why didn't lord Hanuman help Sugriva to kill Vali?

Tags: ramayana, hanuman, vali

We all know that lord Hanuman is very powerful and he was friend of Sugriva, then why didn't he help Sugriva to get his throne back from his brother Vali (*by killing vali*)?

I know Vali was with boon that he will take 50% of power from his opponent who ever challenges him but I am sure this is not the reason behind lord Hanuman not fighting with Vali.

Comment: Another question could be Lord was enough powerful to kill Ravana, then Why didn't he kill Ravan on his first meeting ?

Comment: Hanuman was never so strong to be able to kill Vaali. Vali carried strength of 60000 elephants in his bare hands apart from the boon. Even devatas called him to fight against demons when they felt weaker. Hanuman could not even defeat Ravan and you might heard the story that prior to Rama, Sahastrabahu and Vaali were the only one to defeat Ravan. Even Jambwant was stronger than Hanuman but even he could not dare to face Vaali

Comment: In addition, Vaali was the King of Vanaaras. Hanuman, Jambavan etc were also ministers. Though they knew that sugriva, had been wronged,  though Hanuman and Sugriva were considered good friends.  Also, Hanuman, himself didn't know, about his own powers. Also, remember, Hanuman fell into a swoon when hit by Ravana and when by Hanuman, ravana recovered quiclky and got up to fight again. Hanuman salutes Ravana for his energy and strength and declines to fight Ravana any further. Vaali, just plucked Ravana and put him in his arm pits and roamed around the world. Jambhavan was too old by that time.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  You should cite sources.

Comment: It was known to Hanumaan that only Rama would have killed vali and ravana. Unless Rama killed vali, sugriva would not have agreed to support Rama in searching Sita.

Comment: Hanuman was known as reflection of lord shiva. He was stronger than all vanaras. He was defeat vali. Very easily

Comment: Have you forgot Vardaan of Vali?

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  You should cite sources.

Comment: @AnkitSharma As I discuss in this answer, I don't think the boon of Vali has any basis in Hindu scripture: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/7306/36

Comment: Lord hanuman was still thinking that Vali's heart will change when he will meet the lord Rama. But it was not happened because the vali was so much arrogant that he did not take care even after listening that Shri Ram is with Sugreeva. His wife had told him all about each & every incident that had taken place after joining of Lord Rama to Sugreeva

Comment: @Susanta - Which Ramayana, you are referring to? Hanuman never fought Arjuna, Bheema or Balaraama. Hanuman is servant and devotee of Raama and Lakshmana. Lakshmana is Balarama. So, Hanuman will never fight his own masters. Also, when did Hanuman get ready to fight Raama? Maybe all these hypothetical incidents are in the your own Raamayana? bravo...You need to provide valid references to your answers. Dont write answers based on  stupid TV serials, movies and some folk lore.

Comment: @Krishna Susanta didn't say Hanuman fought Bhima, merely that he showed his power to him.  See the Vana Parva of the Mahabharata: http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03145.htm In any case, if Vanaras wouldn't fight the rebirths of Rama and Lakshmana, why did Jambhavan fight Krishna and Dvivida fight Balarama?  Dvivida and Jambhavan were certainly devotees of Rama.  It's just that they didn't recognize who they were fighting.

Comment: @Keshav - Dvivida fighting Balarama and getting killed by Balarama is different matter. Here, i was addressing something like Hanuman fought balarama, which is nothing but trash. Even, if Hanuman fought balarama, hypothetically, he cannot defeat balarama.

Comment: @Krishna By the way, have you seen my question on the Dvayam? http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7971/36

Comment: @Keshav - I have seen the question. But, i dont know much about the answer.

Comment: I cannot *disagree* more with these answers. One of the serious drawbacks of Hindus nowadays is that we believe what Television Serial show us. As you can see in @Krishna comment, "quickly got up to fight again", it is coming straight from a TV series. Hanumanji's powers are only outmatched by none other than Bhagwan Ram. He could've easily killed Vali if he wasn't cursed for his childhood mischief. He could have killed Ravan and rescued Sitaji if he didn't care for Rama's honor (and so did Sitaji). Hanumanji chose to be captured by Meghnad in Ashok vatika. He honored Brahmastra at that time.

Comment: Here are some deductive proofs of my comments. Vali, however powerful, was killed by Rama with a single arrow. Hanuman didn't even get a scratch with Brahmstra (a weapon of complete and utter destruction) in Ashok vatika. To honor Brahma, he chose to be captured. Now in presence of Ravan's entire assembly, he scolded Ravan for his misdeeds, and managed to break free of his bonds, left Lanka burning in flames and escaped. No one could stop him, not Ravan, not Meghnad and not a single soul in his army.

Comment: @Ravi M Patel - Well, i didnt watch any of those Stupid multiple Hanuman serials which are being telecasted in so many Channels. Please read Yuddha khanda of Valmiki Ramayana. Even Kumbhakarna didnt feel a pinch when he was hit by arrows similar to the one which Rama used to kill Vaali.

Comment: @Ravi M Patel -In Yuddha Khanda of Valmiki Ramayana Ravana hits Hanuman twice which made Hanuman reeling with pain. Even Kumbhakarna beats all the Vanaras including Hanuman and captures Sugriva. Pls read Yuddha Khanda of Valmiki Ramayana. Also, in Uttara khanda the answer is provided why Hanuman didnt fight Vaali? Simple answer is Hanuman didnt remember all his powers due to curse by sages.

Comment: @Krishna, correct, that's exactly what I said in my first comment, "He could've easily killed Vali if he wasn't cursed for his childhood mischief.". And note, I agree with what you say about stupid serials, but Ramayan by Ramanand Sagar cannot be called a stupid adaptation. I'd say it is more than 80% accurate. I hope you'd agree. And we must thank him for his efforts without which only few like you who really read actual scriptures (and it is a very good thing, I admire you for that) would know about Ramayan.

Comment: @Krishna, one more thing, wouldn't you agree that Hanuman was (is) of noble heart and "kartavya-parayan" enough to at least attempt to fight Vali even if he forgot all the powers? I think he would. I think if it was up to him, he would have fought Vali. But he didn't. There could be two possible reasons for that. 1. Sugriv, being the leader, was too afraid to retaliate. Hanumanji, didn't wan't to disobey and start a war against Vali himself. 2. The only other option to war is punishment, which can only be brought upon by a person with such authority. In this case Rama or any Ikshwaku vanshaj

Comment: @Ravi M Patel - Well, i dont know. Uttara Khanda of Valmiki Ramayana has already given the answer. Why do you want to speculate? Moreover, Why only Hanuman, even Jambhavan didnt venture to fight Vaali. Also, Vaali was the sovereign king of all Vaanaras. So, though Hanuman was good friend and well wisher of Sugriva, he wouldnt and couldnt fight Vaali because because even Hanuman wasnt sure that he would win against Vaali. Obviously, because he didnt remember all his powers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Be Happy is right in answering this.

Shri Hanuman ji was certainly more powerful than Vali as well as Ravana. This fact is supported [here, go through 35th and 36th sarga for details](http://web--stock.in/001-Epics-PDF/Valmiki-Ramayan/Part-2/007-Valmiki-Ramayan-Part-II.pdf)
in Valmiki Ramayana.
[image]

The text in image translates as (this is my translation, not the literal one):

> Shri Rama: Undoubtedly, there was no match of the strength that Vali and Ravana possessed, but i believe that even the strength of both of these put together cannot be matched with the strength of Hanuman.

[image]

The text in above image translates as (again my translation):

> Shri Rama: When Vali and Sugriv became enemy of each other; then as forest fire destroys trees, why did Hanuman not destroy Vali in the same way? This is difficult to understand.
>   I believe that Hanuman did not remember his strength at that time. That is why, he was left just to see his beloved Sugriv suffering in such a situation.

[image]

The translation is:

> Shri Agastya Rishi: O' Shri Rama! Whatever you say about Hanuman is all true. There is no match to Hanuman in strength, intelligence and speed.
>   O' destroyer of enemy, Shri Rama! **Sages, whose curses are never vague, had cursed Hanuman that despite having the strength; he would be forgetful of the same.**

The link is about conversation between Rishi Agastya ji and Shri Rama in Uttar Kand.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  This is an English language site, so you should provide an English translation for any text you're quoting from Sanskrit.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: Hello! I edited and translated it in English myself as could not find the English for the images posted.

Comment: Thanks!  If you want to see an existing translation of the Uttara Kanda of the Ramayana, see here: http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/article:valmiki-ramayana

Answer (score 9):

Actually as per hindusim everything that happens is the will of Lord Vishnu.

When Rama killed Valli, he was behind 7 trees, which were considered as 7 saints cursed.

So Rama's arrow also freed those saints from curse and also killed Vali.

Vali's death was written by Rama's hand and hanuman knew that. Actually Rama sent Hanuman to save Sugriva not to kill Valli.

If Rama would not kill Valli then Vaali could not kill Krishna in his next incarnation.

So we can see it as leela of Lord Vishnu. Because untill a person like Vaali does not do sin like harrasing younger brother's wife and throwing younger brother out of kingdom and finally beating him hard to kill him, no god kills anybody. so valli was supposed to do sins. Because of Valli's fate Hanuman did not kill him.

Another fact is Vaali was a king and **Hanuman was not a king**. According to Hindusim only a king can challenge or kill a king.

Comment: Whiich Ramayana mentions Ramaa was behind seven trees while killing Vaali. You need to provide the proof from where you got this info. Otherwise, it is just an opinion of your's and not a proper answer.

Comment: And there no such thing as "only king can challenge a king". Any Kshatriya could challenge another Kshtriya or king. e.g. Lav & Kush accepted Rama's challenge and captured the horse. There were not king at that time.

Answer (score 6):

Rama asks the same question to sages in [Chapter 79 Hanumatkeswara Section 2 Book V of Skanda Purana](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/bitstream/10689/20764/7/Part13_Chapter5_282-321p.pdf) (Pg No- 293).

Sages say that Hanuman was not aware of his strength when Vali was torturing Sugriva. But due to various boons he acquired, Hanuman didn't forget His strengths but He didn't remember his strength for some days. Hanuman didn't remember his strengths when Vali was torturing Sugriva.

> Räma said:  It is due to the might of the arms of this Hanumän, that I
> was able to get back Sitä, Lakshmana, victory, kingdom, friends and
> kinsmen. How could anyone except this great monkey find out the
> detailed news ofJänaki? Even this friend of mine, the Lord of the
> monkeys (i.e. Sugriva), would not have been able to know the news
> about Jänaki. **When the enmity (of the brothers) started (I wonder) why
> Väli was not reduced to ash like grass by this Hanumän with a desire
> to do something pleasing to Sugriva? When the Lord of the monkeys was
> suffering torture, why was he neglected?** I think Hanumän did not
> realize his own strength.

Sages now explain [story](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/1997/3500) of Hanuman trying to Eat Sun and Indra hitting him with Vajra. Skanda Purana narrates slightly a different version from Ramayana thereafter.

> When the infant fell down almost dead due to the blow received from
> the thunderbolt, Väyu (Wind God) carried him on to Mahäkälavana. For
> the sake of his son, Pavana (Wind) propitiated the **Linga** then. As soon
> as he came into contact with the Linga, the monkey rose up like a
> drying plant after being watered. He was fully restored to life, After
> seeing him revived, Pavana was excessively delighted in his heart. He
> took up the child quickly and said: 'My son rose up due to the contact
> with this Linga. Hence this deity will become well-known as
> **Hanumatkeévara**.'
>
> In the meantime Sakra came there surrounded by the
> Suras, holding a garland of blue lotuses. He said: 'Since his jaw was
> shattered by the thunderbolt hurled with my hand, this powerful monkey
> will be called Hanumän. Varuna granted him this boon: 'He will never
> meet with death. Yama granted him immunity from death due to a blow
> with (his) stick. Dhanada granted him freedom from illness. Lustre was
> granted by Sürya. Speedy movement was granted by Pavana, Then the
> following boon was granted by the Linga in the presence of the Devas:
> 'He will not be killed by any of the weapons, Undoubtedly he will
> become unaging and immortal, He will be a terror to the enemy. He will
> grant freedom from fear to his friends. He will be invincible in
> battle.
>
> This the Linga said repeatedly: 'In order to exterminate the
> army of the enemy and to get the favour of Räma always, **he will not
> forget his strength but due to the curse he will not remember it for
> some time.**

Comment: Have you find some scripture mentioning boon of Vali ?..

Comment: @Tezz See [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/367/3500)

Comment: that verse is in commentary of valmikiramayan.net...I'm trying to find its source.. see our discussion in chat...

Answer (score 4):

Vali was king of the *Vanaras*. Moreover, the dispute was only between the two brothers Vali and Sugriva. So it was not right for third person to interfere in their business. But **because Rama was a descendant in the Ikshvaku lineage, to whom the whole land, forests, mountains, etc. belonged [VR - [4.18.6]](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/kish/sarga18/kishkindhasans18.htm#Verse6), Rama had the right to punish him by law, but not Hanumana.**

Another possible cause lies in an [earlier question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/1965/38) you asked. It was may be because, Hanuman didn't remember all his powers. And without knowing all his powers, he couldn't have defeated such a strong personality like Vali (given he also had that [special boon](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/367/38) of taking half of his opponents power). Even Sugriva took a test of Rama's power to be sure that He can defeat Vali.  Hanuman, remembered all his power when Jambvan reminded him at the shore of the sea for flying over to Lanka. By that time Vali was already dead.

Comment: In either way your first line is true, however this is still not the right reason to not to kill Vali.

Answer (score 2):

People, this is not even a debate. Are we really discussing whether a child, who mistook the Sun as a fruit and went on grab and eat it, is all powerful or not?

Vali, Ravan or anyone except the almighty himself are no match for him. It is theoretically impossible to defeat Hanuman. He is one of five immortals, so simply no one can kill him. He has a boon from Brahma that no one can kill him with any weapon in war. His body is tougher than Vajra (the toughest material in the world, better than Adamantium I can assure you. :) ). He is faster than wind, water can't drown him (courtesy of Varundev), fire can't burn him (courtesy of Agnidev), he can shapeshift (courtesy of Suryadev) and he is a nishkam yogi so women cannot manipulate him. (This was actually the reason why Vali and Ravana were punished in the first place.)

One of the reasons why Hanuman didn't kill Vali is because only Ikshwaku descendants, who were the rulers of the region, had the rights to punish Vali for his misdeeds. Hanuman wouldn't disobey Ram. After all, he is an ideal devotee and "das" of Rama which is his topmost power \ weapon. Rama wouldn't let any harm come to his Hanuman.

Those who need a reference, [here it is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanuman#Honours). We all know this to be true.

Answer (score -1):

No where in Srimad Ramayana it was mentioned that  Vali had a boon that he will take 50% of power from his opponent, who ever challenges him.  However, it was mentioned in Ramayana that he is very powerful and fearless.

According to Srimad Valmiki Ramayana, Vali had always been wearing a lustrous necklace, given by his father Lord Indra, on his neck.  It was only when he is breathing his last that he asks Sugreeva to take it before he passes away.

Sri Hanuma shows immense strength and dexterity in SUNDARA KANDA.  He even says that he alone can slay Ravana alongwith his army. Even Ravana acknowledges Sri Hanuma’s capabilities in Sundara Kanda (Sarga 46 Sloka 11 ).

दृष्टा हि हरयः शीघ्रा मया विपुल विक्रमाः |
वाली च सह सुग्रीवो जाम्बवान् च महाबलः || 
नीलः सेना पतिः चैव ये च अन्ये द्विविद आदयः |
न एव तेषाम् गतिः भीमा न तेजो न पराक्रमः || 
न मतिः न बल उत्साहो न रूप परिकल्पनम् |

"Earlier, I saw the Vanara-s of a great prowess like Vali and Sugreeva, the mighty Jambavan, Nila the Chief of army and so on like Dvivida.”

```
 “Their scheme of performance is not so fearful as this; nor their efficacy, nor their prowess, nor their intellect, nor this capacity to change their form or energy at will." 

 A question arises as to why Sri Hanuma,  having so many capabilities, remained as a silent spectator, when Vali banished Sugreeva and grabbed Ruma, the wife of Sugreeva.  Could not he stop Vali with his might?
```

He could have, I think.  From the various situations in which Sri Hanuma’s character was depicted,  I think, Sage Valmiki projected him to be a KARMA YOGI and STHITA PRAGNA.

Being a wise person he knows that if he defeats Vali and hands over the Kingdom to Sugreeva, the latter may not like to take it as till then Sri Hanuma had been his minister only.

A kingly person will not accept such a gift from a minister, as it will be viewed below his dignity.  **That is why Sri Hanuma remained silent and keeps on following Sugreeva.**

However, accepting help from another king/would be king is a different matter.  It is common among kings.

Hence, Sri Hanuma gladly accepted the proposal of Lakshmana to arrange a meeting with Sugreeva, understanding that Sri Rama can slay Vali.