# Who was the father of Vali?

Tags: ramayana, vali

I would like to know that who was the father of Kishkindha King Vali & how did he get the boon the while fighting, his enemy's half of the power will go to Vali ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The father of Vali was Indra.** In [this chapter](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga17/bala_17_frame.htm) of the Bala Kanda of the Ramayana, Brahma tells the gods to have children with Vanaras, so that there will be powerful Vanaras to help Vishnu's incarnation Rama who is about to be born:

> Let mighty and guise changing helpmates be procreated to that truth abiding and valorous Vishnu who is the well-wisher of all of us.  Let monkey-shaped progeny equalling Vishnu's valour be procreated from the physiques of prominent apsara-s and gandharva-s, from the girls of yaksha-s and pannaga-s, and also thus from the bodies of kinnaraa-s, she-vidyaadharaa-s, she-riksha-s and she-monkeys, and they shall be wizards of miracles and audacious ones, in travel they shall have air's speed, bestowed with intellect they shall be the knowers of ideation, and with their divine physique they shall be ineliminable, they shall be endowed with all the assaultive aspects of all missiles, and they shall be untiring in their efforts, like you who thrive on amrita, the ambrosia, unmindful of thirst and hunger.

So then Indra and Surya both have children with the same Vanara woman:

> Indra procreated the lord of vanara-s, namely Vali, who by his physique is like Mt. Mahendra, and the highest humidifier among all the humidifiers, namely the Sun, procreated Sugreeva.

Now as far as Vali having a boon to take half of his enemy's strength, as far as I know that has no basis in Hindu scripture.  The Kishkindha Kanda [mentions](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/kishkindha/sarga17/kishkindhaitrans17.htm#Verse5) Vali having a pendant keeping him alive, but it doesn't describe its power:

> That superb and gem-studded golden pendent given by Indra sustained that monkey chief's lives, resplendence and brilliance.

Also, the translator says [this](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/kishkindha/sarga17/kishkindhaitrans17.htm#Verse48):

> Rama is aware of the boon given by Brahma to Vali aahuuya vaalinam brahmaa dadau varam anuttamam | pratiipavarti nobhuuyaat artha balam arindama ||
>
> Summoning Vali, Brahma gave an unexcelling boon... any combatant will loose half of his strength to Vali shall he confront Vali.

But again, I don't think it's mentioned in Hindu scripture.

Comment: like the link http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga17/bala_17_frame.htm is there any website for Mahabharatham?

Comment: @NagaVemprala Yeah, here: http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/maha/index.htm

Answer (score 1):

Rksaraja, the king of all monkeys was the father of Vali and Sugriva. This info is provided in Uttara Khanda of Valmiki Ramayana, Canto 36, Verses 37 onwards. Just like Hanuman was born with amsa of Wind god to Kesari and Anjana who were Vanaras, Vali (Amsa of Indra) and Sugriva(amsa of Sun god) were born to the suzerian King of all Vanaras called, Rksaraja. After the death of Rksaraja, Vali became the suzerian king of all vanaras and Sugriva was appointed as the prince. From, childhood Sugriva and Hanuman developed unwavering and unwarying friendship, just like the friendship of wind and fire.

Comment: No, Surya and Indra were the fathers of Sugriva and Vali.  See my answer above for a quote from the Bala Kanda.  And here's what the Uttara Kanda says: http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-42 "And Surya too journeying arrived there. They both simultaneously espied that female form and were possessed by desire. What more, their whole body, as soon as they saw her, was moved and the firmness of the mind shaken.  Thereupon Indra begot on her a son named Vali for he originated from her hairs and Surya begot on her another son, who was named Sugriva for he originated from her neck."

Comment: @Keshav - Though Indra and Sun are also father of Vali and Sugriva, respectively, there Vanara father was Rksaraja who was the Sovereign king of all Vanaras. Please read the canto 36 of Uttara khanda which provides this info.

Comment: By the way, do you know anything about Yamunacharya's lost work, the Kashmir Agama Pramanya (as opposed to the regular Agama Pramanya discussed in my question [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6912/36))?  What were the "Kashmir Agamas" defended in that work, and what is their relation to the Pancharatra Agamas?

Comment: @Keshav- Please check the book "Contribution of Yamunacharya to visistadvaita" by Narsimhachary. The author does provide some information about this lost work " Kasmir agama pramanya"

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to Narasimhachary's book.  In any case, I just posted a question about the Kashmira Agama Pramanya here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7422/36 So tell me if you have any information about what the Kashmira Agamas are, their connection to the Pancharatra texts, their connection to the Ekayana Shakha of the Shukla Yajur Veda, etc.