# When did lord Hanuman fight with Ravana?

Tags: ramayana, hanuman, ravana, vali

By reading [@krishna's comment](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2331/why-didnt-lord-hanuman-help-sugriva-to-kill-vali/6881#comment13761_6881) on [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6881/2656), come to know that lord Hanuman was not that powerful to fight with Ravana.

So when did Hanuman fight with Ravana?

Read the comment below

> Hanuman fell into a swoon when hit by Ravana and when by Hanuman,
>   Ravana recovered quickly and got up to fight again. Hanuman salutes
>   Ravana for his energy and strength and declines to fight Ravana any
>   further.

Another thing I want to ask is Did Vali have the power of 60,000 elephants? If so How did he get such power?

I already know about the boon to take half of the energy of his opponents, but power of 60,000 elephants is a different thing.

Another question would be when did Vali fight with Ravana?

> Vaali, just plucked Ravana and put him in his arm pits and roamed
>   around the world.

What is the story behind this?

Comment: "I already know about the boon to take half of the energy of his opponents." As I discuss in [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/7306/36), I'm not aware of any scriptural basis for this claim.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I have read this somewhere "One day, the gods were trying to churn the oceans with a mountain to produce various gems and treasures, but they were not strong enough to do so. Then Vali, who was the strongest monkey on the planet, volunteered and churned the oceans with his strength. Fourteen treasures were produced, and one among them was a beautiful Apsara named Tara, who Vali took as his wife. To thank Vali, the gods gave him a boon where all of Vali’s challengers would immediately lose half of their strength to him."

Comment: I've heard the story of Tara coming out of the churning of the ocean, but as far as I know it's only mentioned in things like the Kamba Ramayana, not in Hindu scripture.  In the Valmiki Ramayana Tara is described as the daughter of Sushena.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the Valmiki Ramayana, Yuddha Kanda, Sarga 59.

In the process, Ravana defeats Hanuman, Sugreeva, Gavaksha, Gavaya, Sushena, Rishabha, Jyotimukha ,  Nala,  Nila and  Lakshmana also.

Finally, Lord Rama alone defeated Ravana in that war.

Check this link for more details http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga59/yuddha_59_frame.htm

Regarding, Vali defeating Ravana, please read the canto 34 of Uttara Khanda of Valmiki Ramayana. Vali just toys with Ravana, unlike any one else. Ravana couldnt even fight him. Vali pressed Ravana in his arm pit and flew over four oceans and performed his sandhya prayers. Vali flew thousands of yojanas arresting Ravana in his arm pit.

Looking at the superior might of Vali, Ravana makes friendship with Vali with fire as the witness (Similar to friendship made between Sugreeva and Lord SriRama)

Ravana and Vali agree that they will both enjoy all kingdoms, luxuries, food etc. Ravana declares that all these will be jointly held and ruled by both Ravana and Vali. All these are clearly, described in Uttara Khanda of Valmiki Ramayana.

Here is the link provided by Keshav Srinivasan to the Vali and Ravana episode in Uttara Khanda of Valmiki Ramayana : http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-39

Comment: First of all, your link to the Yuddha Kanda chapter is broken (you accidentally switched the text and URL).   Second of all, you should add the link to the Uttara Kanda chapter: http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-39

Comment: yes the link is broken, but the link provided by Keshav is working.. but still questions remaining that how Vali had such super power? And why and when hanuman fought with Ravana?

Comment: @Nishantsolanki- The link clearly says in sanskrit and english why and when Hanuman fought Ravana. Regarding super powers of all vanaras including, Vali, Hanuman is given in Uttara Khanda. Moreover, they were born to devathas e.g. Vali was son of Indra, Sugreeva was son of Sun god, Hanuman was son of wind god etc and they were endowed with super powers from their chilhood

Comment: @Keshav- uttara khanda link is not available, so couldnt provide it. There are uttara khanda english translation by M.N.Dutt, available online for free download. I have gorakhpur press Valmiki Ramayana and it conyains uttara khanda also. So, i just provided the details from it

Comment: @Nishant- Corrected the yuddha khanda link details. Now, you should be able to check the story of why and when Ravana and Hanuman fought each other during the Yuddha.

Comment: @Krishna I already found a link to the relevant Uttara Kanda chapter; see my first comment.  You should add that link to your answer.

Comment: @Keshav - I have added the link you provided to the answer. thanks.

Comment: Is it not strange that Ravana defeated these ten vanaras. Yet NOT EVEN ONE of them died at his hands that day? Doesn't make any sense. Vanaras were not immortal.