# Does Anushasan Parva, chapter 88 of the Mahabharata, allow cow sacrifice?

Tags: mahabharata, rituals, practice, cows, sraddha

In the following video, Dr. Zakir Naik says that Bhishma Pitamaha tells Yudhishtira that sacrificing a cow will *satisfy* their dead ancestors for a period of 1 year.

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KwoJhaWeQqk

Is it right? Does the Mahabharata say so?

Comment: I just downloaded that pdf. The above person who did put photo of shloka no 7 is edited. The word gayen is not there. I dont know how to tag that screenshot here but you can visit bori critical sanskrit version from above source. Hypocrat Zakir Naik. Spreading false information.

Comment: Seventh sloka has the word "gaavasya", which means product from cow. I didn't edit it. Did you see Anushasana parava? Why did you mention Zakir Naik?

Comment: Well cow sacrifice is also known as Gomedha which is a vedic sacrifice. So it may be allowed to sacrifice cow but if its avoidable with kheer as mentioned by Keshav Srinivasan we can do that instead of cow sacrifice.

Comment: @DarkKnight Why did you unprotect this post? It has received a lot of bad answers which were later deleted that maybe the reason why it was protected in the first place by the Community user. Besides, it already has several good answers. So we don't need new answers.

Comment: If you think Cow sacrifice is rare in Hindu Society, I'd advise you to search up the "go-sava" sacrifice of the Jaminiya and Taittiriya Brahmana.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Bhishma does say that in [chapter 88](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b053.htm) of the Anushasana Parva of the Mahabharata:

> Listen to me, O Yudhishthira, what those Havis are which persons conversant with the ritual of the Sraddha regard as suitable in view of the Sraddha and what the fruits are that attach to each. With sesame seeds and rice and barley and Masha and water and roots and fruits, if given at Sraddhas, the Pitris, O king, remain gratified for the period of a month. Manu has said that if a Sraddha is performed with a copious measure of sesame, such Sraddha becomes inexhaustible. Of all kinds of food, sesame seeds are regarded as the best. With fishes offered at Sraddhas, the Pitris remain gratified for a period of two months. With mutton they remain gratified for three months and with the flesh of the hare for four. With the flesh of the goat, O king, they remain gratified for five months, with bacon for six months, and with the flesh of birds for seven. With venison obtained from those deer that are called Prishata, they remain gratified for eight months, and with that obtained from the Ruru for nine months, and with the meat of the Gavaya for ten months. With the meat of the buffalo their gratification lasts for eleven months. **With beef presented at the Sraddha, their gratification, it is said, lasts for a full year.** Payasa mixed with ghee is as much acceptable to the Pitris as beef. With the meat of the Vadhrinasa the gratification of the Pitris lasts for twelve years. The flesh of the rhinoceros, offered to the Pitris on the anniversaries of the lunar days on which they died, becomes inexhaustible. The potherb called Kalasaka, the petals of the Kanchana flower, and meat of the goat also, thus offered, prove inexhaustible.

Pitris are spirits of departed ancestors, by the way.  In any case, see my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/8883/36) for the moral justification of animal sacrifice.

Also, it should be noted that the Brahma Vaivarta Purana says that offering meat at the Shraddha ritual is not permitted in the Kali Yuga:

> In this Age of Kali, five acts are forbidden: the offering of a horse in sacrifice, the offering of a cow in sacrifice, the acceptance of the order of sannyāsa, **the offering of oblations of flesh to the forefathers**, and a man’s begetting children in his brother’s wife.

Now like many verses in the Brahma Vaivarta Purana, some consider this verse to be an interpolation.  But this is a moot point, because pretty much no one offers meat in Shraddha nowadays; they use one of the options referred to by Bhishma that don't involve meat.

Comment: Somehow it mirrors Greek practices, like when Odysseus visits the Underworld, he has to sacrifice a goat and allow the ghosts (Pitrs) to take part of the blood before they speak to him.

Comment: Does it specifically say _Cow_ or _Beef_?

Comment: One thing I do not understand why everyone here pronounce _Bhishm_ as _Bhishma_, _Ram_ as _Rama_ etc?

Comment: @user31782 It says "gavyena datte śrāddhe tu saṃvatsaram ihocyate" - gavya means of or pertaining to a cow.  Even cow milk is called gavya, but I think from the context it's clear that it refers to cow meat because in the same verse it also talks about buffalo meat.

Comment: @user31782 That's just a language issue.  In Sanskrit when a noun ends with an a, the a is taken off when it becomes a Hindi word.  So Rama is the original, but in Hindi it becomes Ram.

Comment: I mean how are they actually pronounced, e.g. "Ram Ram satya hai".

Comment: @user31782 Like I said, the original pronunciation in Sanskrit is with an a at the end.  But in Hindi people take the a out.

Comment: So if someone dies then the pundits would pronounce "Rama Rama satya hai". I don't think so. I've listened pundits chanting mantras and they always pronounce it as Ram in every mantra. Perhaps you know it better.

Comment: @user31782 "Ram Ram Satya Hai" is a Hindi expression, so naturally people would pronounce it as Ram as opposed to Rama.  In Sanskrit mantras you're supposed to say Rama.  If people are saying Ram in a Sanskrit mantra they're doing something incorrect.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan by "man’s begetting children in his brother’s wife" you mean Niyoga?  And what do you mean by order of sanyasa? So technically no one can try for Indra's position in kaliyuga .

Comment: @AnilKumar Yeah, it means Niyoga.  And order of Sanyasa means becoming a Sanyasi or ascetic.  Now Gaudiya Vaishnavas (the main people who put importance on this verse) interpret this as a prohibition on becoming an Ekadandi Sanyasi, but that people are still allowed to be Tridandi Sanyasis in the Kali Yuga.  See here: http://gosai.com/writings/is-sannyasa-forbidden-in-kali-yuga

Comment: @AnilKumar By the way, as I mentioned in my answer, many people (myself included) believe that this is not an authentic verse of the Brahma Vaivarta Purana, but rather an interpolation in the text added by someone who was embarrassed by certain Hindu practices.  The Brahma Vaivarta Purana is considered to have a lot of interpolations.  In any case, there are descriptions in Hindu scripture of Ashwamedha Yagnas in the Kali Yuga, for instance by Arjuna's great-grandson Janamejaya.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan What is the Sanskrit work for 'rhinoceros' in the passage quoted above?

Comment: @Naveen The word is khadga: "ānantyāya bhaved dattaṃ khaḍgamāṃsaṃ pitṛkṣaye" http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs13088.htm Khadga originally meant sword, but it became the word for rhinoceros because the horn looks like a sword.  By the way, another scripture that mentions the rhinoceros is the Manu Smriti; see my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/8687/36

Comment: How will such animal sacrifices satisfy dead ancestors if they were pure vegetarian while they lived?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan -You are absolutely correct , the word "Gavya" has other meaning also. And in case of cows the word means either  Cow urine (Gau mutra) Cow dung , or Cow Pats and   dried out circular Pats  are used   homas and yagnas etc. So I think we should refer to" Gavya" as Cow Pats.

Comment: What does this mean - "acceptance of order of sannyasa" is forbidden? lol, is that a joke? Any one can take sannyasa in any yuga and will get Moksha if they are determined enough.

Comment: In anycase beef can be meat of any cattle including cow, buffalo, ox etc so if one wants to avoid cow slaughter he can use this ambiguity of words.

Comment: Those who renunciate the world in old age as per the Varnâshrama system are known as sanyasis while those who renunciate the world in search of moksha are termed as yatis. The Brahmavaivarta Purâna verse prohibits the practice of becoming a sanyasi in old age, not from becoming yatis. The Puranas refer to mendicants who renunciate the world in search of moksha as yatis, but their lifestyle is similar to those who have accepted sanyasâshrama, so we refer them as sanyasi. Those who become yatis renounce the world before they become old, without undergoing vânaprastha or in some case gârhastya.

Answer (score 14):

No. It doesn't support cow sacrifice though cow sacrifice is allowed during [Yagnas](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbr/sbe26/sbe2661.htm).

[Bibek Debroy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bibek_Debroy)'s translation of [BORI](http://www.bori.ac.in/mahabharata_project.html) critical edition is critical edition of Mahabharta. You can read Anushasana Parva of BORI critical edition (Sanskrit) from [here](http://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/unic/mbh13_sa.html).

> मासानष्टौ पार्षतेन रौरवेण नवैव तु |
>  **गवयस्य** तु मांसेन तृप्तिः
>   स्याद्दशमासिकी ||७||
>
> मासानेकादश प्रीतिः पितॄणां माहिषेण तु |
>  **गव्येन** दत्ते श्राद्धे तु
>   संवत्सरमिहोच्यते ||८||
>
> यथा गव्यं तथा युक्तं पायसं सर्पिषा सह |
>  वाध्रीणसस्य मांसेन
>   तृप्तिर्द्वादशवार्षिकी ||९||

This is how Bibek Debroy translates these verses:

> With the meat of ***gavaya***<sup>1</sup> they are content for ten
>   months. With the meat of buffaloes, the ancestors are delighted for
>   eleven months. If the ***product from a cow***<sup>2</sup> is given at
>   a funeral ceremony, the satisfaction is said to last for an entire
>   year. The product from a cow can be mixed with payasam and ghee. With
>   the flesh of vardhinasa, the satisfaction lasts for twelve years.

And footnotes say,

<sup>1</sup> The gayal or mithun. 
<sup>2</sup> We haven’t glossed over this in the translation. The text doesn’t say meat, it says product.

[Gayal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gayal) or mithun is an Ox and not ***Gau*** or cow.

Comment: Nice answer... but it is likely that it is referring meat of cow...as it is used in context of meat as evident from other products... anyway but cows were sacrificed in vedic period... you can read this chapter of Satapatha Brahmana... http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbr/sbe26/sbe2661.htm

Comment: @Tezz Actually, i'm skeptical about various practices described in this Anushasana Parva. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anushasana_Parva#Critical_reception). Yeah, i know that cows were sacrificed in Vedic days as any animal which was sacrificed amidst Vedic chants would get Moksha but not sure about Sraddha ceremonies. Also, cow is described as Theomorphic animal in Atharva Veda and this will contradict Sraddha ceremony.

Comment: I was also thinking the same... Cow is considered highly sacred animal in Atharvaveda....

Comment: The destroyer if you have strong proof. So you can post here like mahabharat book page etc. If u have not yet then u have worng information. Because i was read Mahabharata anushsan parve chapter no. 88..but..

Comment: Please read properly before commenting. There's  no such word as "Gayen" but 8th sloka has "Gavyena". Also, if you want to discuss, please create an account and don't write comments as answers.

Answer (score 11):

No, this is the wrong information given by Zakir naik. But I would like to thank him to read the Anushasana Parva of the Mahabharata or I want to give him a suggestion that he should read properly and then give any speech about our Hindu religion. Now I am showing the proper information about that chapter no 88 - 89 of the Anushasana Parva of the Mahabharata that what Bhishma tells:

*[image: strong text]*

Comment: Can you add English translation of those verses because all people who visit this site may not understand Hindi?

Comment: this is right information.. this page is book of mahabharat..

Comment: firstly i want to say u.. if you do not know sanskart .. then firstly you have to study about sanskart and meaning of word ..here product of cow means curd, dung,milk,urine.. that product we get from cow. but some people showing wrong information about cow. they said product of cow means ''BEEF", that is wrong.. this pic prove that there are not written about "BEEF,"FISH",GOAT, etc..

Comment: this pic prove that there are not written about "BEEF,"FISH",GOAT, etc..     this is the page of mahabharat.......if u offer curd of cow at sraddas(funeral ceremony) then our ancestors remain gratified and with kheer ( which is made by rice and milk of cow) ,food,fruits,mix with ghee at sraddas then ancestors remain delighted and gratified..for full year..

Answer (score -1):

The sacrifice in yajña, recommended, that is not for killing the animal, but it is a testing, how the Vedic mantras are being properly chanted. Because an old animal put into the fire, by Vedic mantras he would come out again with young life. That is sacrifice of animals in the yajña. Therefore in this age there is no such expert brāhmaṇa who can chant the mantras properly or he can behave because the life is very abominable. Therefore, because there is no expert brāhmaṇa, so these sacrifices are forbidden in this age.

http://vaniquotes.org/wiki/In_the_present_age,_Kali-yuga,_animal_sacrifices_are_forbidden_because_there_are_no_expert_brahmanas_who_can_properly_perform_the_yajna

Answer (score -2):

In those places where it is mentioned that a cow can be sacrificed, it is actually referring to a bull, not cow per se.

In the past ages, people used to sacrifice a old bull before fire sacrifice.

They never killed a cow.

Bull is also refereed to as Go/gau etc.